# Encoding accented characters with C#

Tags: c#, postgresql

Whene i try to display a message text from an **postgresql Exception**, the accented characters don't display correctly.

With this code :

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect user name / password\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n" + e.Message);
    return null;
}
```

I get this output :

[image]

And when i try this code :

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    string sMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(e.Message));
    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect user name / password\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n" + sMessage);
    return null;
}
```

I get this output :

[image]

Even if i do this encoding the message dont display correctly, i still dont see the accentued caracters.

Can you please tell me what i missed ?

---

Thing that i test, in the **Postgresql** side, but it's not working yet :

```
SHOW CLIENT_ENCODING;
SHOW SERVER_ENCODING;
```

Both are set to **UTF8**

[image]
[image]

But this not solve my problem Yet, still have the same problem :(

I try with the consol directly, to see if the problem comes from the consol Encoding, but it's seems work perfectly on the console :

[image]

Comment: If the font that has been chosen by the user does not support accented characters, this can happen.

Comment: Please refer to this as well: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/accented-characters-and-messagebox-t3993601.html

Comment: thanks for your response, the message that i try to display is an Exception, i get it from "Pgsql" software, so i don't know how to resolve this problem, and this characters should be display correctly, because it's french langage.

Comment: Did you try including an accented character in one of your _own_ error messages? For example, try `MessageBox.Show("Café");`. If this does appear correctly, then you have a problem with your PgSQL interface. Try `SET CLIENT ENDODING TO...` (Found [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/multibyte.html)).

Comment: See [client encoding](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-CLIENT-ENCODING). Since the database encoding is used as the default, check if the DB's encoding mismatches with UTF8.

Comment: with `SHOW SERVER_ENCODING;` i get : `UTF8`. And with `SHOW CLIENT_ENCODING;` i get : `UNICODE`

Comment: I think that could be the issue. I am not an expert in C#/PgSQL. Please add PgSQL tag in your question so your question is visible to experts. Also, add all these information on your comments to the question. Hope someone figures out the problem.

Comment: Not working yet, i try to fix them both to "UTF8", but the result is the same